# Haskell linux install a module without cabal

Tags: haskell, module, cabal

I have developed a module (M.hs) which depends upon 3 other modules (A.hs, B.hs and C.hs). Now I want to use the module M across multiple other projects. So I have to install this module. But for learning purpose I don't want to use cabal, I want to do it manually. I want to install it in my home dir.

What is a proper course of action? Which files to be created, copied? where? How to use this module in other project?

Additional info:

1. I am using Debian 6
2. I am using GHC 6.12

Answer (score 2):

You say you don’t want to use `cabal`, but would you use `Cabal`?

[cabal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install) is the name of the command line tool provided by cabal-install which can download packages from Hackage and resolve dependencies.

[Cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) is the library that Haskell code uses to drive the compilation (e.g. pre-process files, build in the right order, build variants, generate documentation) and install into the right location.

I would not recommend not using `Cabal`, even for learning purposes, until you want to write a replacement for it. But if you really want to do it, here is the *rough* outline, with enough details to figure out for a good learning experience:

1. Build your files with `-package-name yourpkgname-version`.
2. Link the generated files to form a `libyourpkgname-version.a` file.
3. Create a package configuration file like `/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d/mtl-2.1.2.conf`, and pay attention to `name`, `` `exposed-modules ``, `import-dirs`, `library-dirs` and `hs-libraries`
4. Register package by passing it to `ghc-pkg register`